# So I'm having this problem with rejecting decimals from ((a % 1) != 0)

Tags: c++

So im having a problem with rejecting decimals, Im rejecting any characters but when it comes to decimals it just seems not to be working.  ((a % 1) != 0) was the equation i used

Also, I'm having a problem with the do loop, when the user inputs 'y' or 'Y' it seems to double the last value that was recorded from the previous test. I'm a freshman just trying to learn more so please help me out, guys.

```````
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int whatItDoes(int* a, int* b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b * 10;
    *b = temp * 10;
    return *a + *b;
}


int main()
{

    int a;
    int b;
    bool input1 = false;
    bool input2 = false;
    double temp;
    char again;

    cout << "------------------" << endl;
    cout << "solovesa WELCOME " << endl;
    cout << "------------------" << endl;

    do
    {

   
            while (!input1)                                 //Validation                                   
            {

                cout << "First integer: ";
                string line;
                cin >> line;
                istringstream is(line);
                char dummy = '\0';                           //null termination char marks end of string

                if (!(is >> a) || (is >> ws && is.get(dummy)))           //ws meaning 
                {
                    cout << " " << endl;
                    cout << "WARNING: Characters are not allowed" << endl;
                    cout << " " << endl;
                }
                else
                    input1 = true;
               

 if ((a % 1) != 0)
                {
                    cout << " " << endl;
                    cout << "WARNING: Decimals are not allowed" << endl;
                    cout << " " << endl;

                }
                else
                    input1 = true;      
            }

            while (!input2)                                  //Validation   
            {

                cout << "Second integer: ";
                string line;
                cin >> line;
                istringstream is(line);
                char dummy = '\0';                           //null termination char marksd end of string
                if (!(is >> b) || (is >> ws && is.get(dummy)))           //ws meaning 
                {
                    cout << "Characters are not allowed" << endl;;
                }
                else
                    input2 = true;
            }

            cout << "   " << endl;

            whatItDoes(&a, &b);
            cout << "Final: " << (a + b) << endl;
            cout << " " << endl;

            cin.clear();

            //repeat program prompt

            cout << "Would u like to do another set ? (Y/N)";               //ask user if they want to repeat
            cin >> again;
            //if they say no then exits program but if yes it repeats to top program

    } 
    while (again == 'Y' || again == 'y');



    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
``````
```````

Comment: Print the result of the calculation `a % 1`. It may give some hints

Comment: `a` is an `int`, it can't have decimals. You could read the whole line and check if it has any invalid characters then convert that to an int if it is valid. Other ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370189/validate-integer-input-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Recommendation:**
pass a and b by ref.

```
int whatItDoes(int* a, int* b) --> int whatItDoes(int& a, int& b)
```

**Your Question:**
if I understand your code correctly - an ascii character '.' translates to the numeric value of 46 (google Ascii table). So, 46 % 1 == 0.

You can explicitly check for the decimal, if( (a % 46) == 0 ), but be careful, as 0 % 46 == 0 (but character zero ('0') has a numeric value of 48 ).

Consider what I mentioned about the ASCII table and the numeric values of a char.

Comment: My assignment says " First, rewrite the function so it uses pointers instead of reference variables ". So I changed it to pointers and went on from there.